# Java generic and array types, no not what you are thinking (e.g. arrays from generic types)

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to specify that a generic class has to be an array, or better yet a primitive array.  So far this is what I have got working:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  void process( T data );
}

public class Moo implements Foo<int[]> {
  void process( int[] data ) {
     // do stuff here
  }
}
```

This is all perfectly valid Java code and works because primitive arrays extend Object.  Note that this question is **completely different** from all the other Java array generic questions I keep on finding.  In that situation people want to create an array out of a generic type.

The problem is that type T can be anything that extends Object.  What I want is to do something like:

```
<T extends ONLY ARRAYS>
```

or

```
<T extends ONLY PRIMITIVE ARRAYS>.
```

Is that possible?

EDIT: The end goal would be to add a compile time check on the array type being passed in.  Right now any old object can be passed in and it will compile just fine.  The mistake will only be found at runtime when a class cast exception is thrown.  In fact this is the whole point of Generics in Java, to add stronger compile time type checking.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I agree that "ought" to be possible. My gut feeling tells me that there is no other supertype of the arrays-of-primitive-classes than Object. (There is an isArray() on the Class Class)

Comment: A single interface for processing images with data of different primitive types.  The alternative is to have a different interface for each type, which is a worse kludge.  Example, Foo_S32, Foo_U8, Foo_F32, ...etc.

Comment: Since you can't subtype any array type in Java, what are you after, exactly?

Comment: @PeterAbeles But you still can't read the array elements without reflection or casting to a specific type. Also, primitives include `char` which doesn't seem to fit. And `boolean` which takes a byte per element, and there's no equivalent crumb or nibble type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do this. No class can extend an array, so there will never be a type that satisfies the generic parameter `T extends Object[]`. (Other than `Object[]` itself, but then you wouldn't be using generics.)

What you could do is something like this:

```
public interface Foo<T extends Number> {
    public void process(T[] data);
}
```

But then you might run into performance problems with boxing.

Comment: Not quite right, arrays of a specific type such as String[] are assignable to Object[].  But this doesn't help with primitive arrays.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker The example I gave was moot anyways, arrays cannot be used as a type parameter bound.

Comment: You are right that the alternative approach would kill performance.  After doing a bit more searching I can't find any sort of special language exception which would allow the type of constraint that I want.  Selecting this as the solution since you were the first to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

In Java, type parameters can [only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) be constrained by the subtype relation, and the only common supertypes of all arrays [are](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) `Object`, `Clonable` and `Serializable`. The closest you can get is to constrain to `Object[]`, which is the supertype of all arrays with non-primitive component types, or possibly to `Number[]`, which is the supertype of `Integer[]`, `Long[]`, ...

Even if Java did support such a constraint, how would you do anything useful with that array? You could not read individual elements since you can't declare a variable to hold the results, nor write indivdual elements since you can't write down a expression that is assignable to an array element.

That said, I'd bind the type variable to the component type, not the array type:

```
interface Foo<T extends Whatever> {
    void process(T[] data );
}
```

because you can refer to `T[]` knowing `T`, but knowing a `T extends Object[]` does not directly allow you to refer to the component type.

Edit: Jeffrey correctly points out that array type can not be used in type bounds, i.e. `<T extends Whatever[]>` does not compile, so you definitely have to follow my advice of declaring `<T extends Whatever>` and use `T[]` to refer to the array type.

Comment: The point of wanting to add the constraint isn't so that a generalized class could be written manipulating the array, but to make the API easier to work with.  Right now there is no compile time check and errors will only be caught at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No can do. No "interesting" interface nor any supertype but Object exists for arrays of primitives:

```
public class SOTEST {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr = new int[] {};
        Class c = arr.getClass();
        for(Class clazz:c.getInterfaces()) {
            System.out.println(clazz.getName());
        }

        System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Arrays of X do not have a type hierarchy. Integer[] is not a subclass of Number[].

To get what you want, use the array component type as your type parameter T, and declare parameters and return types as arrays of T.

Comment: -1 for incorrect information: `Integer[]` *is* a subtype of `Number[]`. For instance, `Number[] numbers = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3};` compiles just fine ...

Comment: Well - that's nuts, and it's a hole in the java type system. This

 Integer[] ints = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 Number[] numbers = ints;
 numbers[1] = new Float(4);
 for(int x: ints) {
  System.out.println(x);
 }

compiles, and throws an ArrayStoreException at run time.

Comment: Yes, covariance of arrays does violate liskov substitutability (unless we treat ArrayStoreExceptions as part of the contract of arrays, as the JLS does). However, the runtime check ensures that Java remains type safe at runtime. As to it being "nuts" you are certainly entitled to your opinion, but I think to only focus on the loophole in the type system is a rather restricted view. Arrays are covariant, and are checked at runtime. Generics must be made covariant at each usage site, and are not checked at runtime (actually enabling heap corruption). Which is the better design?